# Image not showing on IOS

Tags: html, ios

I have an application where images are generated in c# code and rendered on browser using data uri. None of the images are showing in IOS, not even in Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/z82dpqj1/1/

```
<img src="src="data:image/bmp; base64,***">
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `;` and `base64`.

```
<img src="src="data:image/bmp;base64,***">
```

Tested with Safari on iOS-14.4

EDIT: Here is screenshot from my iPhone. Are you sure its not your browser?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, but not working on IOS after removing space. Mac OSX 10.14 + Safari 12.

Comment: I've tested it again with codepen and it seems to be working. Are you sure its not your browser? (cache)